# jQuery append() for multiple elements after for loop without flattening to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, loops, append

I have a loop:

```
for (index = 0; index < total_groups; index += 1) {

    groups[index].list_item = $(list_item_snippet);

    // Closure to bind the index for event handling
    (function (new_index) {

        groups[index].list_item.find('.listing-group-title')
                               .html(groups[index].Group.Name)
                               .click(function(e){

            fns.manageActiveGroup(new_index, groups);
            return false;
        });

    })(index);

    // Append to DOM
    mkp.$group_listing.append(groups[index].list_item);
};
```

I would rather not call `append()` each time the loop fires.

I know that I could use a String and concatenate the markup with each loop iteration and append the string to `mkp.$group_listing` at the end, however this flattens the object and the bindings are lost (I am not relying on IDs).

Is there a way to perhaps add my objects to an array and append them all in one go at the bottom without flatening to HTML?

Assumptions:

- `$(list_item_snippet)` contains some HTML defining a list item (and includes an element with class `.listing-group-title`).
- `groups` is a block of JSON defining a 'group' in my script
- The closure works perfectly

Edit:

Found that I can use the following syntax to append multiple elements:

```
mkp.$group_listing.append(groups[0].list_item, groups[1].list_item );
```

But i obviously need to automate it - it's not an array it's just optional additional function parameters so I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: How are you binding the events? inside `manageActiveGroup(...);` ?

Comment: Scroll to the right in the code snippet ;) - sorry, should re-format.

Comment: @Alexcoady you need to see my answer - it addresses your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append an array of elements to a selector you can use this:

```
$.fn.append.apply($sel, myArray);
```

In your case, since it's actually the `.list_item` property of each array element that you need you can use `$.map` to extract those first:

```
$.fn.append.apply(mkp.$group_listing, $.map(groups, function(value) {
     return value.list_item;
}));
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, and well explained. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bind it the way you've done, if you bind it using `on()` like below,

```
$(document).on('click', '.listing-group-title', function() {
    // click handler code here
});
```

You can flatten the HTML and append it in one statement and it'll still work.

**Note:** For better efficiency, replace `document` in the above statement to a selector matching the closest parent of `.listing-group-title`

Comment: But clicking on any `.listing-group-title` would trigger the same event in this case. My loop passes different variable values to the click handler function. Any navigation element would trigger the last-bound index I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the jQuery `add` method to add all your items to a jQuery object. Then append that one object.

http://api.jquery.com/add/

EDIT: Example:

```
var arr = $();

for (index = 0; index < total_groups; index += 1) {

    groups[index].list_item = $(list_item_snippet);

    // Closure to bind the index for event handling
    (function (new_index) {
        ...
    })(index);

    // Add to jQuery object.
    arr.add(groups[index].list_item));
};

mkp.$group_listing.append(arr);
```

Comment: The value of `arr` at the end of the loop is `[]`