# .each() makes the page Freeze

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, each

The idea is to fetch the content from an external PHP file on Page load using jQuery `.each()` function. The problem is the page freezes or keeps on loading and never ends. What would be the issue?

**PHP Page**

```
<div class='caller-div-holder'>

    <div class='calling-div' id='calling-div-1'></div>

    <div class='calling-div' id='calling-div-2'></div>

    <div class='calling-div' id='calling-div-3'></div>

</div>
```

**In the .js file**

```
$('.calling-div').each(function()
{
   var fetch_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
   $.ajax(
   {
     type: "POST",
     url: "page-url",
     data: {var1: fetch_id},
     dataType:"html",
     success: function(data)
     {
       $('#calling-div-'+fetch_id).html(data);
     }
   }); // Ajax
}); // Each function
```

Note:

1. Instead of `$.ajax()` on using `document.write` I found that the function is called for 3 times correctly with the variable **fetch_id** getting the data properly.
2. The external PHP page is checked with sample data just changing the POST to GET and passing the data through GET method. It works.

**Edit 1:**

Adding `async:"false",` reduces the problem intensity. But still the page is considerably slow.

Comment: Why are you using `.attr('data-id');` not `.attr('id');`?

Comment: FYI, jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is intended exactly for doing these types of things.

Comment: @AmitHorakeri He is clearly **not** getting JSON (he's inserting it into the DOM with `.html`, after all); why would you add that?

Comment: Do you actually only have three divs, or do you have more like 10-20

Comment: this is because you are editing the `DOM` inside the each loop...instead save these to a `variable` and edit the `DOM` all at once.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: I am getting multiple values using attributes, one such is `data-id`.

Comment: @abc123: I don't understand that. How can I do that?

Comment: @abc123 why would that cause the page to freeze?

Comment: @KevinB: More than 30 atleast.

Comment: There's your problem. the browser can only send x http requests at a time per host. Consolidate all these requests into one.

Comment: @SuryaS then the attribute name on the div would have to be `data-id`, you need to use `.attr('id');` http://jsfiddle.net/2cesa/ using data-id fetch_id is undefined.

Comment: Editing the DOM inside a tightly nest for loop will freeze the DOM in IE and sometime Chrome and Firefox.  @pitchinnate it happens because you are editing the DOM which is what the user sees, before it can refresh the view to show the user it is adding another element to the DOM...

Comment: @abc123 I have never had that happen. How would you edit the DOM all at once in this instance?

Comment: @Pitchinnate in this situation it is more difficult because he isn't generating the whole section html.  But this SO solves the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219094/jquery-append-for-multiple-elements-after-for-loop-without-flattening-to-html

Comment: to drive the point home here is the run time demo http://jsperf.com/fn-append-apply

Comment: @SuryaS can you tell me the parent element of all these divs? because if so i'd be happy to write a quick jsFiddle that solves this issue for you.

Comment: @SuryaS added a quick solution for you. let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will solve the issue by adding all the `html` at once, this will be faster than the other method...it will still lock the `DOM` at the end when it adds the `html` variable to the html of the parent element.

```
var html = '';

$('.calling-div').each(function()
{
   var fetch_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
   $.ajax(
   {
     type: "POST",
     url: "page-url",
     data: {var1: fetch_id},
     dataType:"html",
     success: function(data)
     {
         html += "<div class='calling-div' id='calling-div-" + fetch_id + "'>" + data + "</div>"
     }
   }); // Ajax
}); // Each function

$('.caller-div-holder').html(html);
```

***Special Note*** I highly recommend using the following to solve this problem:

[jQuery append() for multiple elements after for loop without flattening to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219094/jquery-append-for-multiple-elements-after-for-loop-without-flattening-to-html)

http://jsperf.com/fn-append-apply